# How to recording current screen(not open popup) and audio by muaz-khan WebRTC-Experiment webrtc

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

[muaz-khan WebRTC-Experiment](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Chrome-Extensions/screen-recording)

How to edit the extension to be as I want
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible to do within browser, its the matter of end user privacy.
You can build your own native Windows/Mac application to get rid of this

Chrome is providing screen/window/tab capturing through [chooseDesktopMedia](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#method-chooseDesktopMedia) API, it is available only from chrome extension and we cant call this API from web app.
That demo extension is showing how to use chooseDesktopMedia.

We have no control on the screen selection popup, we can only choose the
 combination of screen/window/tab/audio with the [DesktopCaptureSourceType](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture#type-DesktopCaptureSourceType)